# Pack an int and 2 shorts into a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm having trouble packing an `int`, `short`, `short` into a `long`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```java
int p = 123456;
short x = -567;
short y = 789;

long l = (((long) p) << 32) | (x & 0xffff0000L) | (y & 0x0000ffffL);

int p2 = (int) (l >> 32);
short x2 = (short) (l >> 48);
short y2 = (short) l;
```

produces

```
p=123456, p2=123456
x=-567, x2=1        // bad result
y=789, y2=789
```

The middle value is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift `x` over: replace `(x & 0xffff0000L)` with `((x & 0x0000ffffL) << 16)`.

Then you need to fix the shift to retrieve it: `short x2 = (short) (l >> 16)`.